# Parent background color is missing when I am using position:absolute for child divs

Tags: css

I've a parent div which contains 2 children's inside it, but parent background is missing when I am using `position:relative` for parent `position:absolute` for both children's.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snTLQ/)

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: `height` is missing. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/snTLQ/1/. Absolute positioning will take the children out of flow.

Comment: @abhitalks, can this be done without parent height?

Comment: @Gajen: No. You can't. When you absolutely position children, there is no content in parent which would cause it to grow. The children will get out of the flow and get positioned in relation to the parent's position.

Comment: @panther, I've link a fiddle. Please check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `position: absolute`, the parent's width and height are no longer affected by the child. Therefore, to see it's background, you would have to set a specific height and width so it will grow correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/snTLQ/2/

Comment: Yes, but one of the children must be not `absolute`, preferably the first one, that is on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/snTLQ/4/